# PostgreSQL Selecting some Attributes that are Equal =, others Less Than < in SQL Nested Select Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written an SQL query that has been running for 30 minutes, and I think it has been formulated incorrectly.

The simplified database schema has attributes `CompanyName`, `Customer`, `ExpiryDate`, and `DeliveryDate`.

The below query works well in selecting all of the tuples which were sold to a specific Customer 'Company XYZ':

```
(SELECT a.* FROM certificates a
WHERE (a."CompanyName", a."ExpiryDate") 
IN 
(SELECT b."CompanyName", b."ExpiryDate" 
FROM certificates b 
WHERE b."Customer" = 'Company XYZ') )
```

I want to select a subset of the results of the query above where the `DeliveryDate` of relation `a` (`outer SELECT`) is strictly after the `DeliveryDate` of relation `b` (`inner SELECT`).

This may not make any logical sense, but I must find all tuples which had the `DeliveryDate` changed in the data, so this is crucial.

This is my query that will not complete:

```
(SELECT a.* FROM certificates a
WHERE (a."CompanyName", a."ExpiryDate")
IN 
(SELECT b."CompanyName", b."ExpiryDate" 
FROM certificates b WHERE b."Customer" = 'Company XYZ' 
AND b."DeliveryDate" < a."DeliveryDate") )
```

Comment: It might be best for you to provide a working example of the behaviour you're looking for.  Dummy inputs and the results you're looking for.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The first query is a simple one, that has an "independent subquery". Therefore, this subquery can be fully preprocessed (and is run only once) before undertaking the main query. This is fast.

In the second case, you have a "correlated subquery". A correlated subquery must be run once for each potential row in the main query. That's why this is slow. The more rows your main table has, the slower the query becomes.

Correlated subqueries are inherent slower than non-correlated ones. What can you do about it? Try to use indexes. A simple index will help, and a covering index will make it much faster.

- Simple Index (somewhat faster):

  ```
  create index ix1 on certificates ("Customer");
  ```

  The "Simple Index" includes the columns that correlate to the main table.
- Covering index (much faster):

  ```
  create index ix2 on certificates ("Customer", "DeliveryDate");
  ```

  The "Covering Index" includes all the columns being used by the query, in the correlation, filtering, and data retrieval.

Well, in the end you'll need to try them to see how much they improve your query. But remember that correalted subqueries are naturally slow, by definition.